# cx-icon with custom icon types gives an error when 'strictTemplates' is set to 'true'

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In our project, we realised we cannot use `<cx-icon>` in our templates if `strictTemplates` is set to `true` without using `$any(...)`, from Angular, as a workaround.

We have our own list of `CUSTOM_ICON_TYPE`'s, so after we set `strictTemplates` to `true`, Angular complained about our own icon types. This code:

```html
<cx-icon [type]="customIconTypes.CHEVRON_RIGHT"></cx-icon>
```

gives this error:

```
Type 'CUSTOM_ICON_TYPE.CHEVRON_RIGHT' is not assignable to type 'ICON_TYPE'. ngtsc(2322)
```

Here is an example of our current workaround:

```html
<cx-icon [type]="$any(customIconTypes.CHEVRON_RIGHT)"></cx-icon>
```

Is there any other known workaround for that? Or is an update on `cx-icon` already planned in the future?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/icon-library/#icon-component) the configuration of the icons was designed to be provided for in a different way.

Please try this:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig(<IconConfig>{
  icon: {
    symbols: {
      CHEVRON_RIGHT: "<value of customIconTypes.CHEVRON_RIGHT>",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid it also requires to add new item to enum ICON_TYPE... Maybe in your case it will be enough to override `CARET_RIGHT` but I will open discuss about adding new icons possibility, it seems not extendable enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We already do it like you described, but in case we want a new icon (and not just override existing ones), we need to add a new ICON_TYPE enum.

Comment: Can you also please add a link to the GitHub issue regarding this?

Comment: @FilipeEspósito Done: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/13209